# How to filter rows in database

Tags: javascript, database, date, gettime

I have a small line of code here...

```
        if(todaysDate!==date_encoded_time){
            str +='<div id='div_label'>'+recipe_arr[x].recipe_name+''+'</div>';
        }else {
        str +='<div id='div_label'>'+recipe_arr[x].recipe_name+'NEW ITEM'+'</div>';
        }
```

for todaysDate, I'm getting the value of current date or the date today and for the date_encoded_time, it's the date that was stored in a database.  What I'm trying to do here is when todaysDate matched date_encoded_time, it will show on the app 'NEW ITEM'; but every item says 'NEW ITEM', so how can I select a specific row or display a specific item that will tell the user that it's new, using JS and not PHP..?  By the way it's already connected to the database wherein I used AJAX, but I just need to get the latest record that was added on the database.

Any thoughts? Anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: todaysDate!=date_encoded_time it seems you have an = too many. What's the value of todaysDate and date_encoded_time? If it's the time in milliseconds then they're likely not to be the same. Here is how you get the time in days: Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1440000)

Answer (score 0):

Try embeding a specific class on each  elements and catch up them using jQuery.

I assume the code below is PHP code.

```
if (todaysDate!==date_encoded_time){
    str +='<div id='div_label'>'+recipe_arr[x].recipe_name+''+'</div>';
}else {
    str +='<div id='div_label' class="theClass">'+recipe_arr[x].recipe_name'</div>';
}
```

Then pick up and manipulate them by jQuery like this.

```
<script type="javascript">
    $(".theClass").ready(function(){
        // Manipulation as you would like.
        $(this).html("NEW ITEM");
    });
</script>
```

I didn't check that code but hope this will help you.